# Java: FileNotFound after deploying to server

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I have an issue where I want to load a json file that is in the root folder of my app directory.So i did the simple

```
       File file = new File("assetlinks.json");
```

when I run the application on my local server, the file is served correctly
      but  when I push online it the file is not found
      it throws FileNotFoundException.

Please what am I missing here?

Comment: Please give proper file path

Comment: the file is in the root folder of my application so I assume it does not need a complete file path. And it works locally.

Comment: Provide the absolute path

Comment: the absolute file path would be relative to  my machine, i want thesame path to be used on the server too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging the current working directory, I discovered that it returned an empty string, this is because the app is bundled up in a container and to get resources those resources have to be explicitly added in the docker file, so simply adding the resource to docker solved the problem

```
ADD assetlinks.json assetlinks.json
```

After I did that I was able to get the file using

```
File file = new File("assetlinks.json");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the root of a web app, you need:

```
File file = new File(servletRequest
        .getServletContext().getRealPath("/assetlinks.json"));
```

This turns an URL like path (`/`) relative to the web app's root into a file system File.

(BTW a subdirectory might be a better idea.)

Comment: thank you very much, but I am not using a servlet I am returning the file from an api resource

Comment: You might know `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, or simply log out `file.getAbsolutePath()`. Maybe rights are missing.

Comment: thanks once again, I have tried to get the current working dir using System.getProperty("user.dir") but its returning the correct directory on my system and an empty string on the server. Could this be because the server wrapped in a Kubernetes container?

Comment: Seems so. In that you might do `System.setProperty` or start with `-Duser.dir=`

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I have added an answer on how I solved the problem. Thanks for you help.